# Android application using css for common view of pages

Tags: android, css, view, android-layout, android-styles

I want to make use of css in my android application to make a common view through out the application, please help how to add, implement and map a css in an android application.
Thanks.

Comment: android-styles, as Gabriel has suggested, is the equivalent of CSS in an android application

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little confusing, but [styles and themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) might be what are you looking for.